# Thymeleaf. Strange behavior of __#{}__ - preprocessing operator

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

```
<th:block th:with="title=${ #strings.concat( ' asd ' , '__#{${suite.label}}__' ) }">...</th:block>
```

converts to "asd ??suite_1?", but "??" signs is a strange side-effect which I can't get rid of.

How to get right string?)

Comment: Did you try without of underscores and also without of singlequotes? Like this: `"title=${ #strings.concat( ' asd ' , #{${suite.label} ) }"`

Comment: got   `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: " #strings.concat( ' asd ' , #{${suite.label}} ) " (template: "runinfo" - line 14, col 15)`
and   
`org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 29): Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'`